# python json dumps unicode error

Tags: python, json, unicode

I'm trying to store a dictionary as a json document with utf-8 encoding but I seem to be doing something wrong, can't figure out what. I've posted the stacktrace and function below.

```
def parse_contents(res_dict, file):

content_payload = res_dict['parse']['wikitext']['*']
sections_payload = res_dict['parse']['sections']
db = {}
#parse_captures = ("Owner", "Description", "Usage", "Examples", "Options", "Misc.")

def now_next_iter(iterable):
    import itertools
    a, b = itertools.tee(sections_payload)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

def remove_tags(text):
    import re
    return re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)

for cur, nxt in now_next_iter(sections_payload):

    if cur['toclevel'] == 2:
        head = cur['line']
        db[head] = {}
    elif cur['toclevel']  == 3:
        line = cur['line']
        ibo = cur['byteoffset']
        fbo = nxt['byteoffset']

        content = remove_tags(content_payload[ibo:fbo])
        db[head][line] = content #.encode('utf-8')

with io.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_db:
    s = json.dumps( db, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
                    separators=(',', ': '))
    json_db.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

[image]

Attempt 1:

changed printing to file to this:

```
    with io.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_db:
    s = json.dumps( db, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
                    ensure_ascii=False, encoding='UTF8', separators=(',', ': '))
    s = s.encode('utf-8')
    json_db.write(s)
```

output:
this is confusing because I thought s.encode('utf-8') should change it to unicode.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the json.dumps optional parameter 'ensure_ascii=False', and / or set encoding='UTF8' in json.dumps, not just the file.open() call, which will allow the json package to use it's options to deal with non-ascii data.

See the documentation, here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: updated the question, with your suggestion, no luck :(

Comment: nvm, I'm an idiot , i took out the s.encode in attempt 1 and it worked. Thanks